# Getting "no dependency information available" from Eclipse's m2e, but not from Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven

When loading my Maven project in eclipse, I get an eclipse red x on the pom.xml.  The problems tab says that an artifact is missing.

I can run `mvn package` and all is well.  I get a build successful and I even find the missing jar in my `~/.m2` directory where I expect it.

What gives?  Why is the m2e plugin such a spaz?

I'm using Eclipse Indigo and Maven 2.2.1 in Linux.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _what_ artifact is missing?  You can open the POM and the top of the file (or the POM editor) should show a detailed message.  The fact that `mvn package` when **not using** M2E suggests that m2e and "external Maven" are using different settings.

Comment: I'm not behind the system right now, so I can't give the actual artifact.  I believe you are right about m2e and external maven using different settings.  I think it's related to my proxy, but all of that is specified in my .m2 folder.  Does m2e use a different directory?

Comment: I think by default m2e uses the settings file at HOME_DIR/.m2.  You _can_ however change that in M2E's preferences (Preferences > Maven > User Settings)

Comment: Also, m2e uses an embedded 3.0.x maven, by default.